# Having apt-get automatically downgrade if needed?

Tags: apt, dependencies

I'm still supporting installation of a custom package that I build and distribute (`kurento-dbg`) for Ubuntu 18.04. It is a dummy helper package that itself depends on a variety of debug packages, most importantly `libglib2.0-0-dbgsym` (from the [Ubuntu ddebs repo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages)), but this one is not installable due to a conflict in required versions:

```
# apt-get install libglib2.0-0-dbgsym
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-0-dbgsym : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.9 is to be installed
```

We can confirm the strict dependency from the error message:

```
# apt show libglib2.0-0-dbgsym
[...]
Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1)
[...]
```

Both mentioned versions of this dependency (2.56.1, and 2.56.4) are available in the repos:

```
# apt-cache policy libglib2.0-0
libglib2.0-0:
  Installed: 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.9
  Candidate: 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.9
  Version table:
 *** 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.9 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.56.1-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Doing stuff by hand, this works:

```
# apt-get install libglib2.0-0=2.56.1-2ubuntu1
# apt-get install libglib2.0-0-dbgsym
# apt-get install kurento-dbg
```

But I don't want to have to do the package manager's work. These debug packages are solely used for development workstations in ephemeral environments, so it is perfectly OK to downgrade packages as needed to comply with the required dependencies.

**What `apt-get install` command incantation would be able to downgrade as required and achieve installation of the requested package(s)?**

Is dpkg/apt/apt-get even capable of doing something like this? I cannot / do not want to instruct my users to be fiddling with their system's configs (so no editing files on `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` for pinning or changing priorities), and ideally should not require them to install extra tools that don't come installed by default (e.g. no *aptitude*).

EDIT: **This is a bug of Ubuntu, they published a new version of the library, without updating its dbgsym counterpart**. What I wanted is to find an install command that would be able to overcome this kind of upstream mistakes in the future. Actually, *aptitude* is perfectly able to do it, its dependency resolution is better and it can suggest to downgrade the library package to make their versions match. I just wanted to avoid requesting extra tooling in my user docs.

Comment: This is a job for something like Docker. Trying to fight against the packages maintained by your distribution is not a very practical solution.

Comment: Does using `--allow-downgrades` for `apt-get` work?

Comment: would not be my suggestion "This is a dangerous option that will cause apt to continue without prompting if it is
           doing downgrades. It should not be used except in very special situations. Using it
           can potentially destroy your system! Configuration Item: APT::Get::allow-downgrades.
           Introduced in APT 1.1."

Comment: @jarno no, it has no effect, I'm suspecting that this is because the library (the non-debug package that causes the mismatch) is already installed in the system (or maybe `--allow-downgrades` should actually work, and the fact that it doesn't is a bug on itself?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt` will refuse to downgrade packages that are installed, unless you ask to do it explicitly. Besides that `apt` can pin packages to a specific version so it stays on that version.

You are fighting against a core tool in Ubuntu. I would suggest to find a solution in your software to have it use the newer versions of those libraries or not depend on a PPA and create your own `tar.gz` and include the versions of the libraries you want.

Comment: I concur. Linux is rather the 4th dimension - you can't go back in time either. Compiling against the current libraries is the correct way.

Comment: **This is a bug of Ubuntu, they published a new version of the library, without updating its dbgsym counterpart**. What I wanted is to find an install command that would be able to overcome this kind of upstream mistakes in the future. Actually, *aptitude* is perfectly able to do it, its dependency resolution is better and it can suggest to downgrade the library package to make their versions match. I just wanted to avoid requesting extra tooling in my user docs.

Comment: That would validate  a bug report ;)

Comment: I reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/1989572

Comment: Seeing that apt-get is not sophisticated enough to perform downgrades as needed, even when using the flags that would supposedly *do that* but they don't (using `--force-yes` or `--allow-downgrades` does not make any difference), I'm going to mark your answer because the answer to my question is, in effect, "apt-get is not powerful enough".

Comment: @j1elo cool. The option for it is more likely to kill a system than to downgrade it :X It would really be cool to go from 22.04 back to 20.04 using apt.